# byte array to struct - how to access struct members

Tags: c, struct

I have the following byte array that I am casting to the struct below:
** I know it's not in the proper format here `"0x80",` etc, but in my code it is.

```
unsigned char ReadBuffer[512] = { 80 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 01 00 40 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF F2 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 0F 00 00 00 00 33 20 C8 00 00 00 0C 42 E0 2A 0F 9F B9 00 00 FF}

typedef struct MFT_ATTRIBUTE {
    DWORD dwType;
    DWORD dwFullLength;
    BYTE uchNonResFlag;
    BYTE uchNameLength;
    WORD wNameOffset;
    WORD wFlags;
    WORD wID;
    LONG n64StartVCN;
    LONG n64EndVCN;
    WORD wDatarunOffset;
    WORD wCompressionSize;
    BYTE uchPadding[4];
    LONGLONG n64AllocSize;
    LONGLONG n64RealSize;
    LONGLONG n64StreamSize;
} MFT_ATTRIBUTE, *P_MFT_ATTRIBUTE;

MFT_ATTRIBUTE* mft_attribute = (MFT_ATTRIBUTE*)ReadBuffer[0];
```

When I try to print the members, for some reason I get the some kind of incremental values:

```
printf("%x ",&mft_attribute->dwType);
printf("%x ",&mft_attribute->dwFullLength);
printf("%x ",&mft_attribute->uchNonResFlag);
printf("%x ",&mft_attribute->uchNameLength);

Output:
0x80 0x84 0x88 0x89
```

Can someone help me clarify this?

Comment: Why don't you write `unsigned char ReadBuffer[512] = { 0x80, 0x00, 0x00,` and so on? What you are showing in your code snippet doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting the first element of the array to a pointer to your struct.

```
MFT_ATTRIBUTE* mft_attribute = (MFT_ATTRIBUTE*)ReadBuffer[0];
```

You want to cast a pointer to the first element :

```
MFT_ATTRIBUTE* mft_attribute = (MFT_ATTRIBUTE*) (ReadBuffer + 0);
```

Also as @Wolf pointed out this prints pointers not values pointed to:

```
printf("%x ",&mft_attribute->dwType);
```

You need instead

```
printf("%x ", mft_attribute->dwType);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are printing addresses, not values. That's why the output is increasing this way:

- 0x80 - base address, same as the first member `dwType`
- 0x84 - second member, dwFullLength, sizeof (dwType) apart from start
- 0x88 - third member, uchNonResFlag, again an offset of 4, sizeof(dwFullLength)
- 0x89 - 4th member, the offset is 1, which is sizeof (uchNonResFlag)

Remove the & before mft_attribute in your output code:

```
printf("%x ", mft_attribute->dwType);
printf("%x ", mft_attribute->dwFullLength);
printf("%x ", mft_attribute->uchNonResFlag);
printf("%x ", mft_attribute->uchNameLength);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the other half of the answer.

Comment: Fine. But how does this `{ 0 1 2 }` syntax compile on your computer?

Comment: it doesn't, but my data is created dynamically so I didn't want to spend the effort to add the " "

Answer (score 0):

Change your cast to the following:

```
MFT_ATTRIBUTE* mft_attribute = (MFT_ATTRIBUTE*)&ReadBuffer[0];
```

or to

```
MFT_ATTRIBUTE* mft_attribute = (MFT_ATTRIBUTE*)ReadBuffer;
```